# Optimizing geometry of materials under pressure using VASP

Tags: vasp, geometry-optimization

I am currently trying to reproduce the results of [1], wherein they have pressurized $\ce{Cs_2SnI_6}$ from $0$ to $20$ GPa.

I ran calculations with PBEsol and used the PSTRESS tag in order to optimize the cubic structure. But even though a similar trend is followed, I observe a difference of $0.2$Å  between the experimental data and the simulated one. I will also attach my INCAR file, please let me know if there is anything wrong with it.

#### Results

| PSTRESS | PBESol | PBESol+D3 | Experimental |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 11.5661 | 11.5379 | 12.0655(materials project)/11.65 (other papers) |
| 0.2 | 11.5046 | 11.4745 | 11.647 |
| 3.1 | 10.9858 | 10.9796 | 11.157 |
| 7.2 | 10.6099 | 10.5977 | 10.801 |

#### INCAR

```
 SYSTEM   =  Perovskite

# Electronic minimization
  ISTART  = 0
  ICHARG  = 2
  IALGO    = 48
  PREC= Normal
  ENCUT   = 360
  NELM    = 100 
  LREAL   = Auto.
  EDIFF   = 1E-6
  EDIFFG  =-0.03
  LWAVE   =.FALSE.
  IVDW    = 11

# Ionic minimization
  NSW     = 100
  IBRION  = 2
  ISIF    = 3
  POTIM   = 0.5
  PSTRESS = 31

# Exchange correlational functional 
  GGA = PS

 ISMEAR   = 0
 SIGMA    = 0.026

  NCORE = 4
```

##### References

1. Bounos, G.; Karnachoriti, M.; Kontos, A. G.; Stoumpos, C. C.; Tsetseris, L.; Kaltzoglou, A.; Guo, X.; Lü, X.; Raptis, Y. S.; Kanatzidis, M. G.; Falaras, P. Defect Perovskites under Pressure: Structural Evolution of Cs2SnX6 (X = Cl, Br, I). The Journal of Physical Chemistry C, 2018, 122, 24004–24013. https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jpcc.8b08449.

Comment: paper have used QE which have different pseudo-potential while you are using VASP. Difficult to have one to one comparison but overall trend is same.

Comment: No I am actually comparing with the experimental data. So I am rather looking for input parameters which would lead to better cell parameters as compared to the experimental data

Comment: I would like to add in recent experiments of mine PBE is showing a=11.21 at P=3.1 GPa. Which is much closer(only a 0.6A difference) to the experiment. But isn't PBEsol supposed to give better structural properties. It seems like with PBEsol all the atoms seems to have more interaction due to which the cell becomes smaller

Comment: If your objective is to get DFT results (in VASP) that resemble the experimental structure more, you could try to go beyond GGA level XC functionals. A meta-GGA like SCAN or a hybrid like PBE0 or HSE06 could potentially lead to better structural results.

Comment: What temperature are the experiments at, and what's the thermal expansion coefficient? Is the FCC structure the 0K phase? These are perovskite structures, so there could be quite a rich phase diagram.